# How to get localized names of Finder labels from [NSWorkspace fileLabels]?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nsworkspace

When I use [NSWorkspace fileLabels] I get an array of names for Finder labels. These names are always English. How to convert (or get) them localized?

Comment: Is your Finder running only in English? And if one manually resets the labels to whatever the user prefers, how would *that* be localized?  I would think those labels stay the same no matter what language is set.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, Unfortunately `[NSWorkspace fileLabels]` always brings english versions of label names. Even if you change it to something else...